# How can I get the default divider?

Tags: android

I want to make a form and put a divider between each form element, and I want the divider to have to same style as what is default for the ListView on the platform.

Can I somehow access information about the default divider for ListView and use it for my form?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

This is how it's done in [some Android sources](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts/blob/gingerbread-release/res/layout/item_kind_section.xml)

```
<View
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />
```

Comment: Can you fix the link, please?

Comment: How about "Holo" style if you know? Doing this way it is dark gray instead of blue.

Comment: But, as far as I can see, dividers on the ICS are dark grey.

Answer (score 13):

This will get the default list divider that matches your applications theme:

```
int[] attrs = { android.R.attr.listDivider };
TypedArray ta = getApplicationContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs);
//Get Drawable and use as needed
Drawable divider = ta.getDrawable(0);
//Clean Up
ta.recycle();
```

Answer (score 7):

This is how I do it

```
<ImageView 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="1dp"
  android:scaleType="fitXY"
  android:src="?android:attr/listDivider" />
```

Answer (score 2):

To get default horizontal divider from code you could use:

```
    final TypedArray array = getContext().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
            R.style.<some_theme>, new int[] {
                android.R.attr.dividerHorizontal
            });
    final int defaultDivider = array.getResourceId(0, 0);
    final Bitmap dividerBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(r, defaultDivider);
    final BitmapDrawable divider = new BitmapDrawable(r, dividerBitmap);
```

Then, to also draw it yourself on a `Canvas` in `onDraw`:

```
divider.setBounds(X, Y, X + width, Y + height);
divider.draw(canvas);
```