# What is the default color of a ListView divider line?

Tags: android, android-listview

Currently I am using this code to see the divider lines:

```
medalsList.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(0x99F10529));
medalsList.setDividerHeight(1);
```

What is the default RGB color (as shown in the code above) used on a ListView that hasn't had its divider lines changed?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The default divider is determined by the `listDivider` item in the current theme. For the stock themes, the default divider is one of:

- android:drawable/divider_horizontal_dark (Theme)
- android:drawable/divider_horizontal_bright (Theme.Light)
- android:drawable/divider_horizontal_holo_dark (Theme.Holo)
- android:drawable/divider_horizontal_holo_light (Theme.Holo.Light)

Those drawables can be found in the platforms data folder of your sdk installation.

Answer (score 37):

You can use:

```
<View
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />
```

Refer: [How can I get the default divider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573208/how-can-i-get-the-default-divider)

P.S. Posting it here because Google search seems to land first on this thread instead of the other one.