# How can I get the drawable of the listview Divider to reuse it?

Tags: android, listview, drawable, divider

I have a little tweak in my application: my Listview is placed between 2 LinearLayout that looks like my ListView rows.

That's a little trick that allows me to always display first and last item

and my layout looks like

> [LinearLayout]
>
> [ListView]
>
> [LinearLayout]

I am pretty happy with the result except for one thing: I would like to insert the listview divider between those LinearLayouts and the ListView.

How should I get a drawable (or better, a xml layout) that would looks exactly like the divider?

Comment: The [listDivider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#listDivider) drawable is public & usable directly in your layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ListView.getDivider()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#getDivider%28%29) to get the drawable used by a list view according to Android SDK version and theme.

Comment: I have to wait 5 minutes before accepting (SO gives me a popup telling me to wait), but would it be possible by xml?

Comment: If you don't want to do it in code - go and [show your appreciation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4573725/967142) to this answer.